# Why is "man" pronounced like "Mann"?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

I have listened to multiple sound samples and "man" sounds to me like "Mann". Is there a difference? For example, in "Schwan", "Kran", "Plan", "Vulkan", "Untertan", "Tukan", "Roman", the *a* is long.

Even "LAN" has a long *a*.

Why is it not pronounced long then?

Comment: I wouldn't really say than "Mann" and "man" are pronounced identically. Admittedly, "man" doesn't have a "long a", but a definitely a longer one than "Mann".

Answer (score 6):

Because it was originally the same word as "Mann", which is itself short. There are a few pairs of words in German that are pronounced the same but written differently without any historical reason, just to not look the same.
For example, there is "*dass*" (that) deriving from "*das*" (that) or "*seid*" (y'all are) and "*seit*" (since) which
etymologically should both be spelled "seit".

The Germanic word was originally used to refer to all humans, regardless of sex.
As the meaning of the pronoun "man" (no gender indication) diverged from the meaning of the noun "Mann" (male), it was also useful to spell it another way.

There is actually no hard rule the determines if a single vowel followed by a single consonant is long or short:
"an", "ran", "heran" are also short. As you see, functional words often don't have double consonants despite having short vowels, and "man" is definitely such a functional word.

Comment: Grimms Wörterbuch ( www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=M00799 ) takes "man" originally to be equal to lat. "homo". This has both meanings, "human being" or "man".

Comment: "homo" is of greek origin, meaning "equal (to)" (e.g. a "homonym" is a word equal to another, not a *human word*). Also https://www.etymonline.com/word/Man states that the meaning "adult male person" is of later origin, "wer" and "wif" was used to distiguish sexes before "but *wer* began to disappear late 13c.". Furthermore "homo" in latin meant "human" only, The word for "adult male person" is "vir" (e.g. Cornelios Nepos writes about "De **Viris** Illustribus", not *De hominis Illustribus")

Comment: @bakunin You do not dispute that "man" and "Mann" come from the same root, do you? Should I change it to "was originally the same word as 'Mann' " and "the meanings diverged"? My post does not contain "male" at all.

Comment: @Dodezv, I think that formulation would be better.

Comment: "... regardless of gender" - Don't you mean sex? ^

Comment: @Dozdev: yes, "man" and "Mann" come from the same root - but this root meant "human", not "male person". The word(s) derived from that root (namely "Mann" for "male person") acquired that meaning only later. This is why i took objection with "man comes from Mann" - if at all, it was the other way round: "Mann" comes from "man". The germanic word for "male person" was "wer", hence e.g. "Wergeld" - the money you had to pay for killing a man or "Werwolf" - a man being also a wolf (sometimes).

Comment: @bakunin It is OK to disagree - of course.  But you have to make sure to always maintain a friendly tone on this website. Using formulations such as "utter nonesense" and "troll somewhere else" fails to do so. This is an offense against the code of conduct of this website. Please improve your efforts to stay friendly and kind to others here.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: I agree that "utter nonsense" was a poor choice of words. Still, I have at the very minimum delivered some arguments explaining *why* I am of that opinion and followed up on that. Contrarily, jarnbo used the same poor choice of words without presenting *any* argument whatsoever and even giving proof that he obviously didn't understand what I wrote. This *is* the book-definition of "trolling" and I was (and still am) interested in a discourse with Dozdev.

Comment: @bakunin This is not at all about content, or about "who is right", but exclusively about the tone. I am positive you will be able to state your arguments while maintaining a friendly tone. Please do so in the future. If you feel that a comment is inappropriate, flag it for moderator's attention instead of insulting users here.

Answer (score 0):

The rule you found, is indeed a general rule for pronunciation of German words:

- If after a vowel there is only one consonant in the same syllable, or no consonant at all, then the vowel is pronounced long.

  > mal, total, egal, normal, ...
- If within the same syllable there are two ore more consonants after a vowel, then the vowel is pronounces short.

  > Fall, Ball, Stall, Metall, alt, kalt, hart, ...

But there are many exceptions, sometimes even if the spelling is identical (except for capitalization):

> short: Ich gehe **weg.**
> long: Ich gehe den **Weg** entlang.

There are many reasons for these exceptions. These are the main reasons:

1. German has a lot of loanwords and foreign words that are not original German. But the rule with the number of consonants only applies to originally German words.
2. German is a living language and spelling and pronunciation changed during the centuries.

In case of *»man«* and *»Mann«* it is the second reasons: These words both derive from the same etymological root from which also English *»man«* derives and similar words in many other Germanic languages. It meant *»human«* (without meaning a certain gender), *»Mankind«, »male human«* or *»husband«.* But it also meant *»someone«.* And in the meaning *»someone«* it evolved to the modern word *»man«* while in the meaning *»male human«, »husband«* it turned into *»Mann«,* but the pronunciation of both forms always keept the same.